# UI Path Multi-Bots working for same process automation simultaneously

Tags: rpa, uipath

My process automation is to pick the tickets from servicenow and add them to orchestrator queue. From there I have to assign the tickets to 3 bots sequentially. 3 bots will work simultaneously for the same automation.
Can anyone please suggest me how would i do this in a single workflow/ automation with multi bots. Please explain me the architecture how they would work?

Answer (score 1):

Working with [Queues and Transactions](https://orchestrator.uipath.com/docs/about-queues-and-transactions) means separation of concern. Applying this design pattern in UiPath results in two separate workflows:

1. One workflow to parse servicenow according to your requirements. This workflow is concerned with creating transactions only, essentially populating your queue.
2. Another workflow for fetching transactions and doing the real work (for example parsing an individual ticket's history, sending out email notifications, et cetera). I would recommend using UiPath's [ReFramework](https://github.com/UiPath/ReFrameWork) as the basis for this workflow (it is built-into the latest releases of Studio).

Scheduling [jobs](https://orchestrator.uipath.com/docs/about-jobs) then happens in Orchestrator. For example, you may want to run the first process with a single robot - overnight, every 4 hours - as often as necessary to keep your queue populated, or depending on your service level requirements.

The other process could then be scheduled to run on as many machines (robots) as required. If you built your workflow based on ReFramework, your robots will automatically process the next item in the queue, update its status, or retry failed items, if configured.